# WSS and CAG , _layout pages break

Tags: iis, sharepoint, citrix, wss-3.0, sharepoint-services

Alright,

I've searched everywhere and I cannot find the answer, due to the rarity of our setup.

WSS 3.0/IIS 6.0/WinServer 2003

We have a sharepoint site that is in good shape, almost. Its TCP and SSL port are uncommon and need to be rerouted to work properly. This is where the Citrix Access Gateway (CAG) comes in play. It will redirect any request from URL (something.something.com) to the correct SSL port on the correct server. My AAM is configured to Default something.something.com and nothing else, since the CAG will provide the port. We use FBA, and require SSL.

This works perfectly for everything that is safe or that is anything that an end user can see, but if I try to add a webpart, it errors out. Whereas if I add it internally, or bypass the CAG the webpart adds fine. The same goes for most of the _layouts pages, like _layouts/new.aspx. If I add a Link List/Doc library on the something.something.com, it errors out (Page cannot be displayed) and the page won't display, but if I try it with an internal address it will work fine.

I found that if I am trying to add something or doing anything administrative, the site will navigate to the pages that I need to go to fine, but when i actually ADD something the URL will change from something.something.com to something.something.com:SSLport, thus erroring out the site. The URL with the SSL port shows on the Site URL when navigating to Site Settings. However, if I bypass the CAG, using the internal address the _layouts page works like a charm and i can add anything. All the CAG does is reroute a DNS request to the provided server and port.

I've tried reextending the application, no luck same thing.

I've tried changing the AAM to hide the port and the CAG rejects it.

I've tried to recreate a new webapp/site collection with the same rules on the CAG, same thing occurs.

Correct me if I'm wrong, and please provide me with some feedback and answers. Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

Is it the CAG or the Alternate Access Mappings (AAM)?

Comment: refer to http://serverfault.com/questions/177354/sharepoint-site-settings-add-on-ssl-port-number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to [Sharepoint site settings add on ssl port number?](https://serverfault.com/questions/177354/sharepoint-site-settings-add-on-ssl-port-number)