# Sharepoint site settings add on ssl port number?

Tags: iis, sharepoint, port-forwarding, wss-3.0

WSS 3.0 
IIS6/WinSever2003
CAG

We have several WSS sites on a SharePoint WSS box that talk to the outside, all of which are SSL enabled. So you get a CAG(Citrix Access Gateway) to translate the 443 port to the local ssl port on the server.

Everything is set up and works fine until you get into the Site Settings and start rooting around, it seems like a very unstable link library. Links will try to use the local ssl port number instead of the 443 standard; it will try to skip the step. Is that the site? Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the CAG trying to translate the port number intelligently. If I run all the IIS sites on port 443 with CAG's "content switching" feature, the site runs fine. IIS will reject it initially but the vbscript called [here](http://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-configure-ssl-host-headers-in-iis-6.html) basically tells IIS UI to stop whining. Also if you restart IIS without running those scripts, and have two or more sites with the same SSL port, it will halt. Must input the hostheaders on each site in IIS to match that of the context switching rule in the CAG